# SSE additions of chars

Tags: c, sse

I have got a vector of 16 char that contains either 0 or 1 and I would like to add each 4 non-overlapping elements using SSE.

A simplified version of the code without vectorization looks like this

```
char a[16]={1,0,0,1 ,0,0,1,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,1};
char sum1 = a[0]  + a[1]  + a[2]  + a[3];
char sum2 = a[4]  + a[5]  + a[6]  + a[7];
char sum3 = a[8]  + a[9]  + a[10] + a[11];
char sum4 = a[12] + a[13] + a[14] + a[15];
```

In my application, the length of the vector is much larger than 16 but it is always a multiple of 16. I get this vector using other SSE logical operations that provide me with a good speedup so I would like to know how I could vectorise those additions. Below is the full code where vec1, vec2 and vec3 have the same length n (multiple of 16) and vector counts is n/4.

```
void myfunc( const char *vec1, const char *vec2, char *vec3, int *counts, int n){
  __m128i *r1   = (__m128i*)vec1;
  __m128i *r2   = (__m128i*)vec2;
  char *a = vec3;
  char temp[16] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));

  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i+=16, r1++, r2++, a+=16 ) {
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)a, _mm_and_si128(*r1, *r2));

    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)temp, _mm_or_si128(*r1, *r2));

    char size = a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3];
    if( size == 0 ){
        memcpy(a, temp, 4*sizeof(char));
        counts[k]++;
    }
    k++;

    size = a[4]+a[5]+a[6]+a[7];
    if( size == 0 ){
        memcpy(a+4, temp+4, 4*sizeof(char));
        counts[k]++;
    }
    k++;

    size = a[8]+a[9]+a[10]+a[11];
    if( size == 0 ){
        memcpy(a+8, temp+8, 4*sizeof(char));
        counts[k]++;
    }
    k++;

    size = a[12]+a[13]+a[14]+a[15];
    if( size == 0 ){
        memcpy(a+12, temp+12, 4*sizeof(char));
        counts[k]++;
    }
    k++;
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you want your output sum1..sum4 to be packed? uint8? uint32?

Comment: @Nayuki I just need to test whether these variables are equal to 0. In this case they are chars (It was int in my first post)

Comment: In that case, you can test if each 32-bit word is 0. The sum of the 4 bytes will be 0 if and only if the 32-bit word is 0.

Comment: Avoid using `char` for non-text data. `char` can be either signed or unsigned depending on compiler and even compiler options. A better alternative is to use `int8_t` or `uint8_t` from `stdint.h`/`cstdint`.

Comment: If your chars are only 0x00 or 0x01, you could also use the `__popcnt` intrinsic on each set of four chars, reinterpreted as `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing bytes you can compare integers.  Load four integers from `a`, `temp` and `counts` into SSE registers ( call them `a4`, `tmp4`, and `counts4` in the code below).  Then you can process four integers at once with SSE.  This assumes that counts is a int32 array.

For example let's assume a4 = {0,3,0,4}, counts4 = {1,2,3,4}, and tmp4 = {5,6,7,8}.  In the code below
`test` will be {-1, 0, -1, 0}.  Subtracting that from counts gives counts = {2,2,4,4}.  Logical AND of `test` with `tmp4` is {5,0,7,0}.  Adding that to a4 gives a4 = {5,3,7,4}.  This should do what you want.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i+=16, r1++, r2++, a+=16, k+=4 ) {
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)a, _mm_and_si128(*r1, *r2));
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)temp, _mm_or_si128(*r1, *r2));

    __m128i a4 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)a);
    __m128i tmp4 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)tmp);
    __m128i counts4 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&counts[k]);

    __m128i test = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(_mm_set1_epi32(0), a4);
    a4 = _mm_add_epi32(a4, _mm_and_si128(tmp4,test));        
    counts4 = _mm_sub_epi32(counts4, test);

    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)a, a4);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)counts, counts4);        
}
```

Comment: This still has some redundant store -> loads.  But yeah, the major optimization here is that if the byte elements are unsigned, testing the whole 32bits for non-zero is sufficient.